# What's the supremum of $]-\pi; \pi[ \cap Q$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I'm trying to find the supremum and infimum of this set .

$$I = ]-\pi; \pi[ \cap Q$$

The problem is that it accept a least upper bound (resp :  greatest lower bound) since it's a bounded set and non empty . However there's an endless rational numbers that are bigger than all elements of this set due to the density of $Q$ in $R$ , also from the archimdean property we know that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exist some rational number smaller than $\epsilon$ . Which mean that I can always find a smaller number then any rational I suppose to be the supremum

Can anyone explain why this has or hasn't any $sup$ or $inf$ while it's a non empty set and bounded ?

Comment: You are sure you mean $$]-\pi;\pi[\; \cup\; \Bbb Q$$ (what's not bounded) and not $$]-\pi;\pi[ \;\cap \;\Bbb Q$$ (what is bounded but has a $\sup$ and $\inf$)

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Because I can say that  $-4 < I < 4$

Comment: No, not for $$]-\pi;\pi[\; \cup\; \Bbb Q$$. Obviously $$5 \in ]-\pi;\pi[\; \cup\; \Bbb Q$$ because $5 \in \Bbb Q$... So i assume you meant $$]-\pi;\pi[\; \cap\; \Bbb Q$$, right? AND: Do you mean a $\sup$ in $\Bbb R$ or a $\sup$ in $\Bbb Q$? This is important!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you meant $(-1,1)\cap\mathbb Q$.

Since $\pi$ is an upper bound of $I$, $\sup I\leqslant\pi$. Actually, $\sup I=\pi$, because if $x\in\mathbb R$ is such that $x<\pi$, there's a rational $q\in(x,\pi)$ and, in fact a rational greater than $0$. Therefore $x$ is *not* $\sup I$. So, $\pi$ is the least upper bound of $I$.

By a similar argument, $\inf I=-\pi$.

Comment: Can't I find an irrational number smaller than Pi and bigger than all elements of this set ? Let's say the difference between $\pi$ and this irrational is extremly small ?

Comment: @DeltaWeb No, you cannot, because between any two real numbers there's a rational number.

Answer (score 0):

Set $A:=(-π,π)\cap \Bbb Q$. First of all, $\forall x\in A: x< π$, so $π$ is an upper bound of $A$. Secondly, suppose an $\epsilon>0$; from the density of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$ there exists a $q\in \Bbb Q$ (an interpretation of density is that between any two real numbers there exists a rational), such that $π-\epsilon<q<π$, so $q\in A$. Consequently, by the characterization of supremum we get $supA=π$. q.e.d.